# Makefile C++11 error

Tags: c++, c++11, makefile, gnu-make

I'm learning about makefiles. What I tried is writing my own one after a little reading. The problem is, I always get errors connected with c++11 standard, even though I put the compiler flag needed into makefile. Here is the error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: 
#error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming 
ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and 
must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
```

And here is the makefile:

```
CC = g++
LD = g++

NAME = app
OBJ_DIR = obj 
SRC_DIR = src 

CXX_FLAGS = -std=c++0x

SRC = $(shell find $(SRC_DIR) -type f -regex ".*\.cpp")
OBJ = $(subst $(SRC_DIR), $(OBJ_DIR), $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(SRC))))

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    $(LD)  $< -o $@ $(CXX_FLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    $(CC)  $< -o $@ $(CXX_FLAGS)

clean:
    rm $(NAME) $(OBJ_DIR) -rf
```

Notice that I've put CXX_FLAGS after checking out other questions on stack overflow, but to no avail. I still get the same error. It's like make is ignoring my flag. Is there a solution to this?

And yes, I can compile with -std=c++0x flag without make, so my compiler is not a problem obviously.

Comment: `make` should print out each command as it executes it.  What `g++` invocation immediately precedes the error?

Comment: @cdhowie g++    -c -o src/normal.o src/normal.cpp 
It looks like it ignores my flag.

Comment: So the problem is not with the C++11 flag at all.  Your actual question is "why is my makefile rule not being used."  If it were I would expect the line to be `g++ src/normal.c -o obj/normal.o -std=c++0x`

Comment: Random guess: You need $(CXX_FLAGS) before the $<

Comment: Okay, I'm a beginner. Thanks for correction. Any ideas?
@MatsPetersson nope. Tried that.

Comment: @MatsPetersson No. His rule is not being used at all.

Comment: Yeah, saw that comment just after my comment... :(

Comment: I would suggest adding a rule like this: `test: echo $(SRC); echo $(OBJ)` (with newlines where appropriate) and then execute `make test`.  Perhaps the content of these variables is not what you expect.

Comment: You say the output of make is: g++ -c -o src/normal.o src/normal.cpp If so it is ignoring more than your flag, it tries to put normal.o in src which is why it doesn't match the rule. Why OBJ would end up being src/normal.o I don't know tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the directory `obj` exist?

A better way to write this would be:

```
OBJ = $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SRC))
```

You can add `$(info OBJ = $(OBJ))` etc. after these lines to print them out.  Basically the results of these operations don't match your pattern rules, so make is using the default pattern rules.

I strongly discourage this kind of thing (using `find`) though.  I always, always type out the source files I want to compile.  It doesn't take more than a few seconds to add a new file, and it ensures you don't start throwing random junk into your program when you least expect it.

Your compile command is also wrong: you've forgotten the `-c` flag which is important.  I recommend people just use the same command as the default rules (run `make -p -f/dev/null` to see the default rules).:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
        $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

This does require you to use the standard flags variables (i.e., `CXX` not `CC` and `CXXFLAGS` not `CXX_FLAGS`) but that's a good idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Its not actually using your rule for building the object file.  Comment it out and you'll see that it still invokes "g++ -c".

Part of the problem is that the command subst you are using to define OBJ interprets its arguments as literals.  Rewrite it as

```
OBJ = $(subst src, obj, $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(SRC))))
```

and you'll at least get the desired OBJ.

Comment: why? how can I change that?

Comment: line defining OBJ isn't working right... still trying to figure out why

Comment: This is really interesting. After doing that, I get:

        make: *** No rule to make target `obj/normal.o', needed by `app'.  Stop.

Answer (score 1):

You have spaces at the ends of the lines that define `SRC_DIR` and `OBJ_DIR`. This means that `subst` won't do anything, since it's looking for `"src "` rather than `"src"`.

In turn, this means that it will try to build `src/whatever.o` rather than `obj/whatever.o` and, since there is no rule for that, it will fall back to the default rule rather than yours.

Once you've fixed that, you'll need to add `-c` to the compile command, to produce an object file rather than an executable.

Comment: Yes, this was a key problem. Spaces in defining obj_dir and src_dir